# How to seach and locate data from an access database table and update another table with relevant fields which have changed

Tags: ms-access-2007, delphi-7

I have an access database with table1 with 3 field names i.e item name, stock in and stock out. The database uses an Adoquery and Datasource from Delphi 7 to update data in the table1. I am using the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  ADOQuery1.Locate('Item name',Edit1.Text,[]) ;
  ADOQuery1.Edit;
  ADOQuery1.FieldValues['Item name']:=edit1.Text;
  ADOQuery1.FieldValues['stock in']:=edit2.Text;
  ADOQuery1.FieldValues['stock out']:=Edit3.Text;
  ADOQuery1.post;
end
```

This code only works when there is a single item to be updated from the edit1 box. I need a code that can search for multiple item names at once and update the relevant item names that have changed field values. What I have tried is use the above code to store data on a separate temporary table2 with similar field names, but I don't know a code that can search and locate item names from this separate table2 then update the relevant fields in table1 that have changed according to item names

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you want to type in multiple values for `[Item Name]`and an equal number of values for `[stock in]` and `[stock out]`

And then you want to locate the record that matches each value for  `[Item Name]` and update it to your database

One option would to use `3 Memo controls` in stead of `3 Edit controls`, then you can type multiple values at once.

Now all you need to do is put the code you already have in a loop, that reads all values from the the first Memo.

here is an example

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  ADOQuery1.Open;

  for i := 0 to MemoItemNames.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    // ALWAYS test if the record can be located, else you are editing a random record !!!!
    if ADOQuery1.Locate('Item name', MemoItemNames.Lines[i], [])) then
    begin
      ADOQuery1.Edit;
      ADOQuery1.FieldValues['stock in']  := MemoStockIn.Lines[i];
      ADOQuery1.FieldValues['stock out'] := MemoStockOut.Lines[i];
      ADOQuery1.post;
    end; 
  end;
```

This needs extra coding off course to check if everthing is valid, for example the number of lines in each Memo must be the same, or the format of the `stock in` value, and so on...

There might be better solutions to your problem, so if you tell us what problem you are trying to solve maybe we can suggest a more elegant solution

Comment: Hi @GuidoG, Thanks for clarification. The real problem is where a customer comes and orders an item name then I type the item name in 'edit1 box'. I have another search 'Button' that I use to retrieve relevant information such as price, stock in, stock out from the database according to what is saved from a specific item name. Then I have a save 'BitBtn1' when I click, does this

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do here. I think it would be best to create a new question and explain your logic as much as  you can